# How to use regex beginning of line with Select-String?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code,

```
Write-Output "$(Get-Content $alerfile | Select-String $(Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Format $filtdate) -Context 0,1000000)"
```

I need to return only the string in the beginning of line, I tried:

```
Write-Output "$(Get-Content $alerfile | Select-String ^$(Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Format $filtdate) -Context 0,1000000)"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: remove the `Write-Output` AND the quotes. the 1st is not needed & the 2nd will cause strange evaluation patterns.

Comment: Please show us the value of `$filtdate`

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add information along with input file sample, input variable definition, actual results and expected results.

Answer (score 5):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) commented, you need to remove the `Write-Output`.
Also, you're overdoing it with the date in the pattern.

Next, the `Select-String` cmdlet also has a `-Path` parameter, so you don't need `Get-Content` for this.

I suggest something like this:

```
# insert the datetime format you need here; this is just an example
$filtdate = 'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss'
# get yesterdays date formatted using the $filtdate template above
$refdate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString($filtdate)
# find the string beginning with that formatted date and return the results
Select-String -Path $alerfile -Pattern "^$refdate" -Context 0,1000000
```